# react web conflict in dependecy tree

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

i was trying to learn webpack and i have downloaded webpack-dev-server and i got this problem how to resolve this

> frame@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
dependency:

"webpack": "4.44.2"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in
the tree:

C:\Users\jacob\node_modules\webpack (version: 5.24.2)
anually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in
   the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\jacob\node_modules\webpack is outside your
   project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something
   in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above
:-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jacob\frame
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-scripts start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-28T02_36_44_243Z-debug.log

Answer (score -3):

You should not use your own webpack config with create-react-app. If you really want to do so, do `yarn eject`or `npm eject`. It will give you access to CRA's webpack config. If I were you, I'd just start a project from scratch by downloading React as a simple library, and set everything up with Babel + Webpack. It will be much easier to learn.